# function return (MySQL + Spring)

Tags: mysql, spring, function, jdbctemplate

I'm having problem in using a function created in MySQL through code that uses the class Spring JdbcTemplate.

When I test the function directly in the Workbench works correctly, returning true or false according to past entries. However, when I try to get the result via Java code always returns false, which leads me to believe this is some type conversion failed.

**Why is variable 'result' always false?**

- function

  ```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  FUNCTION `COMPARA_QTDE_EMPRESA`(AG INT, P INT, ANO INT, AINSERIR INT) 
  RETURNS tinyint(1) DETERMINISTIC  
  BEGIN  
    DECLARE TOTAL_EMPRESA_PESQUISA INT;  
    DECLARE TOTAL_EMPRESA_AGENTE INT;  

    SELECT IF(COUNT(*), EP.TOTAL, 0) INTO TOTAL_EMPRESA_PESQUISA  
      FROM CTRLPRODUCAO.EMPRESA_PESQUISA EP  
      WHERE EP.AGENCIA = AG  
      AND EP.PESQUISA = P  
      AND EP.ANO = ANO;  

    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(EA.TOTAL), 0) INTO TOTAL_EMPRESA_AGENTE  
      FROM CTRLPRODUCAO.EMPRESA_AGENTE EA  
      WHERE EA.AGENCIA = AG  
      AND EA.PESQUISA = P  
      AND EA.ANO = ANO;  

    RETURN 
      IF(TOTAL_EMPRESA_PESQUISA = 0
         , FALSE
         ,(TOTAL_EMPRESA_PESQUISA < (TOTAL_EMPRESA_AGENTE) + AINSERIR));
  ```

  END
- Java code

  ```
  (...)  
  Object[] args = new Object[4];  
  int[] tipos = new int[4];  
  args[0] = ag.getId();   tipos[0] = Types.INTEGER;  
  args[1] = p.getId();   tipos[1] = Types.INTEGER;  
  args[2] = ano.getAno();   tipos[2] = Types.INTEGER;  
  args[3] = total.getTotal();   tipos[3] = Types.INTEGER;  

  boolean result = (Boolean)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject("SELECT COMPARA_QTDE_EMPRESA (?, ?, ?, ?)"), args, tipos, Boolean.class);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `boolean` is an alias for `tinyint(1)`.
This means that you are using the correct type.

Note that 1 = true, 0 = false.

So if you want to get the result in your java code, all you have to do this test the return value against `0`.

Change the java code to:

```
boolean result = (getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject("SELECT COMPARA_QTDE_EMPRESA (?, ?, ?, ?)")
                                                   , args, tipos, Integer.class) != 0);
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but it didn't work. Continues returning false. Leveraging your idea, I changed the code to "boolean result = (getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt("SELECT COMPARA_QTDE_EMPRESA (?, ?, ?, ?)"), args, tipos) != 0);"  , but also didn't work. Always gets result = 0.